# Would this take 3 querys?

Tags: android, parse-platform, pfquery

my question is pretty simple...

I have 3 classes.. 
-An Event class
-An Invite Class
-and a user class.

Every row in invite has a pointer to the user class and a pointer to the event class. To show what user was invited to what particular event..

So my goal is for each event is to be able to retrieve for each event, the list of invited users, and those invited users profile images.

I can do this just fine... but seems like it would take a lot of querys..
My logic right now is:
Query for Events
With each specific event returned query for the event, query for the invited users
THEN for each invited user query for their profile pictures.

it just sounds like a lot of queries and am nervous this could be slow or effect performance... wasn't sure if there was a simplier way or something to do with pointers. Or maybe a way I could condense the querys into two, after returning each user be able to retrieve their profile pictures as well..

Thanks!
Any advice would be awesome

Comment: I think you will need to use SQL Joins to achieve what you want with just one query (in case if you have event id with you)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow the "Event" and "User" instances to maintain their own pointers to their "Invitation" references (this is considered a double-linked list) then you can more easily move out from the "Event" context to the "User" context instead of being restricted to the "Invitation" being the holder of all connections.

If you are still confused, please click this link to wiki's ["Doubly linked list"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)

To conclude, if you create these doubly linked lists, then you will want to:

1. Iterate over the invitation references of the event
2. Iterate over the users of the current invitation
3. React in accordance to the specific user (this may also require you to examine if the user has been invited more than once through different invitations)